# ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Tags: flutter, database-connection, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am facing an issue with my flutter project while trying to establish a google sign in.
I followed the steps in this article:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-integrate-your-ios-flutter-app-with-firebase-on-macos-6ad08e2714f0/

No i am facing this issue:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/zagliz/Desktop/testa/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Try flutter clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the IOS project (Runner) in XCode, navigate to `Signing and Capabilities` and select a development team.

Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nice Yassine,
My error was similar: `Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths`

## Rule of thumb 1

For flutter development on ios...

We should always run:

`flutter build ios`

Before opening *Runner.xcworkspace* on xcode.

This command will prepare a newer and ready version of your `Runner.xcworkspace` file: download cocoapods dependencies (run `pod install`), for instance.

## Rule of thumb 2

For any ios native development on XCode...

You should probably want to set some `Development Team`.

Select your main `.xcodeproj` >> tab `Sigin & Capabilities` >> Team

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Running these commands in terminal :

```
$ cd your_project_path
$ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
$ rm -fr ios/Pods
$ rm ios/Podfile
$ flutter clean
```

Answer (score 0):

My case: Missing Debug.xcconfig, Release.xcconfig.

My solution: Create a new project => run => Go to folder: ios/Flutter and copy 2 files.